# Using Mysql to do multiple INSERT on linked tables (Key constraint error)

Tags: mysql

[The ER model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMNAW.png)

Basically the question i got in my assignment was to: Create a procedure for entering a new game name and developer name. It may look like
following: [It may look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzGeu.png)

And I did following command to make this possible:

```sql
Delimiter // 
Create PROCEDURE Games_insert (p_Name varchar(64),p_Released INT,
p_Mode varchar(45), p_Engine varchar(45),
p_GameName varchar(64), p_Developer varchar(45))
 
BEGIN 
Insert into game(Name, Released, Mode, Engine) VALUES (p_Name, p_Released, p_Mode, p_Engine);

Insert into developedby(GameName, Developer) VALUES (p_GameName, p_Developer); 
End //
```

BUT when i try to use the Procedure I get this back:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`-serverdetails-`.`developedby`, CONSTRAINT `fk_developedBy_Game` FOREIGN KEY (`GameName`) REFERENCES `game` (`Name`))

This is my first course in SQL (We use MYSQL workbench btw) and I have no idea to solve this, have searced the error and more but cant find solution/solutions to this. (English is not my native language, please explain in a simple way)

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, what RDBMS are you *really* using? That SQL is *not* T-SQL and that error isn't a SQL Server error, so I assume the former.

Comment: Mysql workbench

Comment: That is an IDE-like application, but that means you are using MySQL *not* SQL Server. (Saying you are using MySQL Workbench when asked what RDBMS you are using is a bit like answering "Microsoft Word" when asked what operating system you are using. It *implies* the correct answer, but it's not the correct answer.) Please don't tag conflicting technologies; doing so makes it harder to help you not easier.

Comment: Okay first time posting, thought the people doing sql server was doing the same

Comment: In your procedure is necessary to use `p_GameName` since it should be the same as `p_Name`? And in the insert in developedby the game name must be the same, right? Try using the same variable.

Comment: What should i change in the code? remove GameName from insert into developed by? When I did this for example: call Games_insert('Battlefield 2042','2021','Multi-player','Frostbite','Frostbite','EA DICE'); I got the constraint error

Comment: Update @EvgeniEnchev I saw it now, i wrote the engine twice when calling the procedure so basically it wouldnt allow me to connect them

Comment: ```.. CONSTRAINT `fk_developedBy_Game` FOREIGN KEY (`GameName`) REFERENCES `game` (`Name`) ..``` - i.e. the value inserted into two mentioned columns must be the same. Whereas you insert `p_Name` and `p_GameName` into these columns, and these values differs. As a result - integrity error.